# Vector of Maps fill - Compiler fail?

Tags: c++, matrix, dictionary, sparse-matrix

I`m new in C++ programming and try to write some sparse matrix and vector stuff I as a practice.
The sparse matrix is build of a vector of maps, where the vector accesses the rows and the map is used for the sparse entries in the columns.

What I was trying to do is to fill a diagonal dominant sparse matrix with an equation system for a Poisson equation.
Now when filling the matrix in test cases I was able to provoke the following very weird problem, which I broke down to the essential operations.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <ctime>

int main() 
{
    unsigned int nDim = 100000;
    double clock1;
    // alternative std::map<unsigned int, std::map<unsigned int, double> > mat;

    std::vector<std::map<unsigned int, double> > mat;
    mat.resize(nDim);

    // if clause and number set
    clock1 = double(clock())/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    for(unsigned int rowIter = 0; rowIter < nDim; rowIter++)
    {
        for(unsigned int colIter = 0; colIter < nDim; colIter++)
        {
            if(rowIter == colIter)
            {
                mat[rowIter][colIter] = 1.;
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "time for diagonal fill: " << 1e3 * (double(clock())/CLOCKS_PER_SEC -  clock1) << " ms" << std::endl;

    // if clause and number insert
    clock1 = double(clock())/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    for(unsigned int rowIter = 0; rowIter < nDim; rowIter++)
    {
        for(unsigned int colIter = 0; colIter < nDim; colIter++)
        {
            if(rowIter == colIter)
            {
                mat[rowIter].insert(std::pair<unsigned int, double>(colIter,1.));
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "time for insert diagonal fill: " << 1e3 * (double(clock())/CLOCKS_PER_SEC -  clock1) << " ms" << std::endl;

    // only number set
    clock1 = double(clock())/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    for(unsigned int rowIter = 0; rowIter < nDim; rowIter++)
    {
        mat[rowIter][rowIter] += 1.;
    }
    std::cout << "time for easy diagonal fill: " << 1e3 * (double(clock())/CLOCKS_PER_SEC -  clock1) << " ms" << std::endl;

    // only if clause
    clock1 = double(clock())/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    for(unsigned int rowIter = 0; rowIter < nDim; rowIter++)
    {
        for(unsigned int colIter = 0; colIter < nDim; colIter++)
        {
            if(rowIter == colIter)
            {
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "time for if clause: " << 1e3 * (double(clock())/CLOCKS_PER_SEC -  clock1) << " ms" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Running this in gcc (newest version, 4.8.1 I think) the following times appear:

```
time for diagonal fill: 26317ms
time for insert diagonal: 8783ms
time for easy diagonal fill: 10ms !!!!!!!
time for if clause: 0ms
```

I only used the loop for the if clause to be sure the it is not responsible for the speed lack.
Optimization level is O3, but the problem also appears on other levels.

So I thought let's try the Visual Studio (2012 Express).
It is a little bit faster, but still as slow as ketchup:

```
time for diagonal fill: 9408ms
time for insert diagonal: 8860ms
time for easy diagonal fill: 11ms !!!!!!!
time for if clause: 0ms
```

So MSVSC++ fails, too.

It will probably not even be necessary to used this combination of if-clause and matrix fill, but if... I'm screwed.

Does anybody know where this huge performance gap is coming from and how I could deal with it?
Is it some optimization problem caused by the fact, that the if-clause is inside the loop? Do I maybe just need another compiler flag?
I would also be interested, if it occurs with other systems/compilers, too. I might run it on the Xeon E5 machine at work and see what this baby makes with this devil piece of code :).

EDIT:

I ran it on the Xeon machine: Much faster, still slow.

Times with gcc:

```
2778ms
2684ms
1ms
0ms
```

Comment: Where's the vector of maps? I only see a map of maps in your code.

Comment: Sorry, wrong version I was playing around with. Thanks for the hint, I fixed it. Interesting: The times are more or less exactly the same, maps of maps is one or two ms slower than vector of maps (nothing close to 8 seconds).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. Generally, neither 'Hi' at the top nor 'Thanks in advance' or your name are needed at the bottom.  We know who from the identity box.  The greetings are not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious performance issue would be allocations within your map. Each time you assign/insert a new item in a map, it's got to allocate space for it and sort the tree appropriately. Doing that thousands of times is bound to be slow.

It's also very significant that you're not clearing the maps after your first loop. That means your subsequent loops don't have to do as much work, so your performance comparisons are not equivalent.

Finally, the nested loops are obviously going to be doing an order of magnitude more iterations than your single loop. From a strict algorithm analysis standpoint, it may be doing the same amount of actual work on the data. However, the program still has to run through all those extra iterations because that's what you've told it to do. The compiler can only optimise it out if there is literally nothing being processed/modified in the loop body.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ran every iteration alone before I posted to make sure that is not the problem and it is indeed not. The allocation (at least in this case) has a cost near to 0. Your second point is interesting, I will think about that. I'm just glad that not the method using vector of maps itself is the problem but the iterations during the filling. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

In the first loop, the runtime system is doing loads of memory allocation, so it takes a lot of time on memory management.

The other loops don't have that overhead; you didn't release the allocation done by the first loop, so they don't have to repeat the memory allocation and it doesn't take anywhere near as long.

The last loop is optimized out by the compiler; it has no side effects, so it doesn't get included in the program.

Morals:

1. memory allocation has a cost.
2. benchmarking is hard.